# How do I install sensor_msgs package?

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all.
I would like to use hokuyo_node in Gumstix with Ubuntu.
To this end, I installed ROS on Gumstix by native build.
The hokuyo_node needs 8 dependencies, so I downloaded sensor_msgs package which is one of the dependencies of hokuyo_node.

$ svn checkout https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_msgs/trunk/sensor_msgs
$ rospack profile
$ rosmake sensor_msgs

However, it shows "No makefile". So I created one dummy package using "roscreate-pkg" and copy Makefile to sensor_msgs from newly created dummy package.

However, it shows "no cmake_minimum_required" so I added following.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)

Then, I do rosmake again, then it shows following.

Unknown CMake command "catkin_project"

Do you know why?

Note that, I installed ROS with very basics, so there is no sensor_msgs package in default.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12715/how-do-i-install-sensor_msgs-package?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-01-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't use the version from trunk unless you are involved in the development of the package. Which distribution did you install? Electric? Then use the following svn command to check out the complete stack common_msgs:

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_msgs/tags/electric/ common_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-23**:
Note that you are checking out the `common_msgs` stack, not just the `sensor_msgs` package. While some packages may work on their own, the stack is the ROS unit for release and install.

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-01-22**:
This works! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try the following commands:

```
roslocate info sensor_msgs > /tmp/sensor_msgs.rosinstall
rosinstall ~/ros /tmp/sensor_msgs.rosinstall
```

Assuming ~/ros is your ros workspace.

EDIT: And if you don't have rosinstall, check [here](http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall).

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-24**:
it is not necessary to install. If you have installed ros electric full, you should have installed that package. You only have to execute rosmake to have the access to that messages. In the past I had that problems with ROSJava. it is easy. Cheers

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-22**:
The command should be `roslocate info --distro=electric sensor_msgs`. Otherwise you will end up with trunk again.

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-01-22**:
It is first to know roslocate command. Thank you very much!